# How change values in dataframe based on another in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

**Hi,**
 i have two dataframes and i want to change values in first dataframe where have same IDs in both dataframes,
suppose i have:

```
df1 = [ID  price
       1     200
       4     300
       5     120
       7     230
       8     110
       9     90
       12    180]
```

and

```
df2 = [ID    price   count
       3       340     27
       4       60      10
       5       290     2]
```

after replace:

```
df1 = [ID  price
       1     200
       4     60
       5     290
       7     230
       8     110
       9     90
       12    180]
```

my first try:

```
df1.loc[df1.ID.isin(df2.ID),['price']] = df2.loc[df2.ID.isin(df1.ID),['price']].values
```

but it isn't correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming `ID` is the index (or can be set as the index), then you can just `update`:

```
In []:
df1.update(df2)
df1

Out[]:
    price
ID       
1   200.0
4    60.0
5   290.0
7   230.0
8   110.0
9    90.0
12  180.0
```

If you need to `set_index()`:

```
df = df1.set_index('ID')
df.update(df2.set_index('ID'))
df1 = df.reset_index()
```